# Rise in temperature of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, temperature

How to calculate rise in temperature of IRF3205PbF MOSFET  if Vds=10v and Ids=5 amps?

Comment: It depends on how it's cooled.  How is it being cooled?   Also, is this a homework question?

Comment: Google "thermal resistance"

Comment: Shripada Nakshathri - Hi, Your question has been voted "[closed](/help/closed-questions)" as it needs more details to clarify *exactly* where you are stuck. Please [edit] the question to [add more context & details](/help/reopen-questions) - Can you add your schematic (at least the relevant part)? What approach(es) to answering your own question have you already tried? Why were they not successful for you? Are you familiar with MOSFET Rds(on) and how its value can vary? What is the actual project? || Within reason, including more context is usually better than less. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First find the power dissipated. You need to know the gate voltage. If you have plenty of gate voltage, then the Rds = 0.008 ohms. If not, it will have a higher resistance, see the tables in the datasheet. P = I^2 * R = 0.2 W.

If you don't have a heatsink, then the thermal resistance from junction to ambient is 62 degC/W. Temp rise = 0.2 W * 62 degC/W = 12.4 degC. This is assuming no switching. If you are switching fast, then the heat dissipated during the transitions can be much larger.